# Proving n^2 - 10n is not O(n) by contradiction

Tags: big-o, time-complexity, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity

I have the solution however I don't understand a part of it.

Want to prove: `n^2-10n` is not an element of `O(n)`.

Assume the contrary that `n^2 - 10` is an element of `O(n)`

There must exist `c > 0` and `n0 > 0` such that for all `n >= n0`, `n^2-10n <= cn`

Rearranging the above equation we get `n<=c+10`

***This is where I get lost***

Let `k = 1 + max(n0, c+10)`

`k >= n0` however it is not the case that `k <= c+10` so we have derived a contradiction.

**Question**: What is `k` and why are we assigning it `1 + max(n0, c+10)`

Comment: `k` is a value for `n` which breaks the assumption.

Comment: I understand that much. What I'm struggling with is comprehending the logic used to construct k.

Comment: `k` is defined as bigger than `c+10` (because 1 is added to the result of `max`) . In that case, assumption  `n <= c + 10` will fail for `n = k`. Already max is granting `k` is bigger than `n0` to satisfy requirements of assumption, so this shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see: part of understanding this is to intuitively see why the contradiction exists; the theoretical details often come as a consequence of your intuition.

You know that `n^2 - 10n` is `O(n)` if `n <= c+10` for every `n` that is greater than or equal to `n0`. Remember that `c` is a constant, so this means that `c+10` (which is also a constant) must be greater than or equal to every `n` that is greater than or equal to `n0`. Intuitively, you can immediately see this is not possible, as a constant cannot be greater than infinitely many numbers.

What does that mean?

Well, you can pick any value for `c`, and I can immediately tell you some `n` that is greater than `c+10` and thus violate the requirement `n <= c+10`. For example, if you give me `c = 1000`, I can say "ok then, I choose `n = 1011`".

So, if you give me `c`, and I give you `n = c+10+1`, you lose the game; every `n` that is greater than or equal to `c+10+1` violates the requirement `n <= c+10` (and remember, the requirement *must* hold for every `n >= n0`).

Now, knowing that I will always choose `n = c+10+1`, you could be evil and complicate things by choosing some `n0` that is greater than `c+10` to invalidate my answer. For example, you say "ok, `c` is 1000". And I say: "fine! `n` is 1011 - there, I found a value that violates the constraint.". But then you say: "No you didn't! Because I choose `n0 = 2000`". This invalidates my answer because we concluded earlier than the condition `n <= c+10` must hold only for every `n >= n0`. In this example, 1011 is not greater than or equal to 2000, so my answer is invalid. I can't pick anything less than 2000.

That's why you need `max()`: to validate `k` for any `n0`. With `k = max(n0, c+10)+1`, you *always* get a value that violates the constraint `n <= c+10`, no matter how crazy you get with picking either `c` or `n0`.

So, with this improvement, you'd tell me: "I choose `c = 1000`." And I, to prevent your next move, say: "Ok, and what value do you choose for `n0`?" You choose -10000, or 5000, or 100000000000000000000. It doesn't matter. If I reply with `max(n0, c+10)+1`, I always win :)

I hope that makes it clear now.